# Solr updating index

Tags: solr

There were around 10 million records in the db that we indexed and we are glad to have done this as we are seeing high performance benefits by getting the records from solr instead of db.
This data is used in reporting.

Currently we are keeping flat data in the index. For example:

```
Itemid, Companyname, Username, Status
```

As soon as item's status change for example from Received to Sold, we call the solr api to update the record. All is working very well. We have the index updated in realtime, report works well.

**Question 1: Now in future lets say, a user updated the company name from Company A to Company B, OR maybe username from Mike to Jimmy, how are we suppose to handle this?**

**My thoughts**

1. Listen to the user and company update event and update only those solr indexes where name = old name
2. Keep the id for company and user in the index instead of names. And after fetching the records from solr, hit the db again to get the updated name. This would be a mixed approach, where major fields come from index and only such fields come from db table

**Question 2: I am calling solr update to update the indexes for status transistions for every call. Now is there a better way to do this? Am i missing anything in terms of performance hit in future or when frequency of status transitions increase?**

**Question 3: Lets say, in future a requirement comes to show one more column in the report that is not yet indexed. Whats the standard acceptable way for doing that?**

Kindly share your expert advice on this please.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Now in future lets say, a user updated the company name
>   from Company A to Company B, OR maybe username from Mike to Jimmy, how
>   are we suppose to handle this?

We have an equal case and what we did is using the solr data import handler. On DB side we added an `LAST_MODIFIED` column. On every update of an row, the DB automatically changed the LAST_MODIFIED` timestamps to "now".

On Solr Side we run an data-import jobs by calling the [Data Import Request Handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler), like that:

```
http://solrhost:8888/solr/mycore/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=false&optimize=false
```

In that case the Data Import Request Handler runs an DB query with an where clause on LAST_MODIFIED. Take a look at [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Delta-Import_Example).

For this it is important, that you have defined an unique Id on solr, like your `Itemid`

> Question 2: I am calling solr update to update the indexes for status
>   transistions for every call. Now is there a better way to do this? Am
>   i missing anything in terms of performance hit in future or when
>   frequency of status transitions increase?

See Question 1. It's an alternative way, but not sure, if this is faster.

> Question 3: Lets say, in future a requirement comes to show one more
>   column in the report that is not yet indexed. Whats the standard
>   acceptable way for doing that?

For me it is: adding the new field to solr, restarting solr. I probably would reindexing all the documents. Reindexing is necessary, if also exiting documents get additional informations.